# How do I prevent Drupal from sending an email to the admin every time a new user is created

Tags: 7, emails, users

I've inherited maintenance of a drupal 7 site from another group.  Currently, every time a new user account is created the admin is sent an e-mail about it.  The admin wants this disabled.

I've been unable to find what's sending the e-mail.  There's no workflow rule for it, and the Trigger module is disabled.  Admin Notify doesn't have any setting turned on for new users, and visitors do not require admin approval in order to create their accounts.

Some of the research I've done suggests that this is drupal core functionality with no settings attached to it.  If that's the case, how would I go about stopping it?  Any ideas on where else the setting might be for the e-mail?

Comment: if you user creation not important event, why you don't change email of admin, or in admin email  create a filter to this email don't bothering you :( . do you have developing knowledge?

Comment: They still want to receive other emails, so changing the admin e-mail address isn't really an option.  They would rather have the email not show up at all than have a filter, but if no one knows how to do that, then we'll have to do that.  I'm new to drupal development, but I'm decent with PHP.

Comment: @zhilevan changing the admin's email is not a smart solution.. you'll get your SMTP full of _delivery failure notice_ and things like that.

Comment: p.s: I read you have already searched around but it's worth a try: have you tried to google for the subject of the emails?

Comment: They didn't want to send me the email that they were receiving before, and now they've changed their minds and don't want this problem solved at all anymore.  I'm starting to think that the email never existed in the first place... :S
So, for now, this issue is closed.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Do the email sent to the admin have the link to activate the user's account?

If so, go to: `example.com/admin/config/people/accounts`

Check the REGISTRATION AND CANCELLATION paragraph (should be the 2°): if `Visitors, but administrator approval is required` is checked, every time a user create an account an email is sent to the admin to let him approve/refuse the user new account.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  The "Who can register accounts?" radio selection is set to just "Visitors".

Comment: Dont know then.. I should be working on drupal tomorrow, so if noone answer before i'll give a look ;)